# Can a mesh be morphed into a fluid simulation?

Tags: mesh, uv, geometry-nodes, fluid-simulation, topology

I'm trying to create a melting animation using fluid simulation. However, I need the simulation to have the same topology as the original mesh. I tried using the method in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134339/170417) answer, but my object's shape is too complex for using the shrinkwrap modifier. I also tried using geometry nodes, but I couldn't find a way to transfer the position of the simulation to the original mesh, since the simulation doesn't have a UV map and the index changes constantly.

Comment: i guess if you want your object to liquify it can't keep it's geometry, why don't you use a Geometry object as fluid?